# What is the significance of the Olympic logo?

Tags: history, olympics

I'm curious about the history and meaning of the five ring Olympic logo.  When was this logo designed, and does it have any symbolic meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The symbol was originally designed in 1912 by Baron Pierre de
>   Coubertin, co-founder of the modern Olympic Games. According to
>   Coubertin, the ring colours with the white background stand for those
>   colors that appeared on all the national flags that competed in the
>   Olympic games at that time.

[Olympics History - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_symbols)

> The five rings represent the five continents. They are interlaced to
>   show the universality of Olympism and the meeting of the athletes of
>   the world during the Olympic Games. On the Olympic flag, the rings
>   appear on a white background. Combined in this way,  the six colours
>   of the flag (blue, yellow, black, green, red and white) represent all
>   nations. It is a misconception, therefore, to believe that each of the
>   colours corresponds to a certain  continent.

[**For Complete History and Other details Refer**](http://www.olympic.org/documents/reports/en/en_report_1303.pdf)

Hope this helps.