# WASP win probability prediction for cricket

Tags: cricket

I'm a programmer looking at implementing the WASP predictor for cricket in python.
I could find one formula for calculating the target score in the first innings, in the blog: http://offsettingbehaviour.blogspot.com/2012/11/cricket-and-wasp-shameless-self.html

I found one implementation in R: https://github.com/sodhanipranav/WASP

However, none of these describe the actual calculations involved in getting a win probability percentage in the second innings.

I did find one question asking for similar details, but at a non-programmer level.
[How is the WASP calculated in cricket?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/how-is-the-wasp-calculated-in-cricket)
That question has no satisfactory answer either. Also, there's almost no literature about this elsewhere.

Can you please tell how are the wasp scores -  win probability in second innings are calculated? Please provide the details: formulae involved and how each of the input variables are individually calculated.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate, as any answers to this would be good answers to the other question as well; the practical answer is almost certainly "the algorithm is proprietary".

Comment: Agreed. It might be proprietary. Since it's almost seven years since the question has been asked first, I thought it could be given another chance. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed - but we strongly prefer to have one question on a subject, rather than multiple with answers then getting scattered in multiple places. If you want to draw more attention to that question, you can either [propose an edit to it](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/3933/edit) to bring it up to date, or when you have some reputation here, use that reputation to [add a bounty](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to encourage others to answer it.